# Firefox and Internet Explorer do not position relative to parent if given position absolute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-position

I'm having a problem with `position: absolute;` inside of a container with `position: relative;`

I think, the default behaviour is, that child elements having `position: absolute;` are positioning theirselfs relative to their parent container, if that one has `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;`

While trying out this, i found out that FF and IE (newest versions), are showing a different behaviour, placing things absolute to the page.

Am wondering why? Its concerning a drop down menu, where the submenus are taken out of the viewport by `left: -9999px;` and while hovering they get `left: auto;`

In Chrome, it works fine.
Sorry if this question was already asked - but using such words to search just shows normal problems with position.

Code:

```
<div id="steuerung">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>

    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Sublink</a> </li>
     <li><a href="#">Sublink</a> </li>
     <li><a href="#">Sublink</a> </li>
     <li><a href="#">Sublink</a> </li>
     <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#steuerung li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
div#steuerung ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 99%;
}
div#steuerung ul li:hover ul {
    left: auto;

}
```

complete Code here: www.step-town.com/new/

Greetings

Comment: I have added it above, sorry.

Comment: [Worked for me](http://jsfiddle.net/67Xhh/) on FF 14 and FF 15, as it should.

Comment: Even on the website? (see above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/3Nh86/

I think the best way for this, without Javascript, is to use "display: none" and "display: block" on your ul submenu.